# Hide imageview in android with titanium appcelerator?

Tags: android, imageview, titanium, show-hide

Hi I want to hide the image in android application for that i write the following  code.

eachChecktech.hide();
eachChecktech.visible=false;

i got the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hide' of undefined

it is not working for me please see and let me know any suggestions.

Comment: full code? so that we could predict your problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have defined imageView with name "eachChecktech".
2. Check if you have created eachChecktech inside loop or function and trying to hide it outside [local object cannot have global access] .
3. define eachChecktech outside the functions and loops so that it could be available  for hide or show or visible setting when there is requirement